# How to echo every parent page title?

Tags: php, pages

I have like 5 parent pages and would like to echo all their title's on the front page.php. Maybe with get_the_id(); but don't know how.

Comment: i already answered, but i'm not sure if i do get what you actually need. you navigated to a page and you want to show its parents? than my answer is for you. if not, please clarify..

Comment: thanks for your answer. I have what I need :) @honk31

Answer (score 1):

Check [Post & Page Parameters](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Post_.26_Page_Parameters) or [get_page_children()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_page_children).

```
<?php
global $post;
$args = array(
    'post_type'      => 'page',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'post_parent'    => $post->ID,
    'order'          => 'ASC',
    'orderby'        => 'menu_order'
 );


$parent = new WP_Query( $args );

if ( $parent->have_posts() ) : ?>

    <?php while ( $parent->have_posts() ) : $parent->the_post(); ?>

        <div id="parent-<?php the_ID(); ?>" class="parent-page">

            <h1><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h1>

        </div>

    <?php endwhile; ?>

<?php endif; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer. The $post->Id is empty i get nothing when i try this

Comment: Depending on how your theme/plugin is structured you could use `get_the_ID()` in place of `$post->ID`. If `get_the_ID()` won't work, you can grab the global `$post` object & retrieve the ID from it.

Answer (score 0):

i would go for [get_ancestors](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_ancestors). it will return an array of ID's that you can use for whatever you want..

```
$anchestors = get_ancestors( get_the_ID(), 'page' );
if (!empty($anchestors)) :
    foreach ($anchestors as $anchestor) :
        echo get_the_title( $anchestor );
    endforeach;
endif;
```